# I have a Problem with my Minecraft::tickEntity on my Minecraft Server

Tags: server, minecraft, lag, tps

Im running a minecraft Server on a: Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU E5-2620 v2 @ 2.10GHz
I only play with up to 5 friends. I dont know how to fix the "lags" without to use a plugin which limit the mobs.
Here are the timings:
https://timings.aikar.co/?id=0fee38d9fe2f4351a7f651e59b8d313f

Answer (score 0):

Try installing plugins such as [ClearLagg](https://www.spigotmc.org/resources/clearlagg.68271/), [automated restarts](https://www.spigotmc.org/resources/1-8-1-16-1k-users-ultimateautorestart-need-an-autorestart-plugin-grab-the-best-one-today.64414/) and try making the server into onlinemode = true as it performs better.

If you know how to use Java, you can just limit the amount of mobs/entities spawning, then keep checking in a loop if the time == your time you set for example 3 am and run `/restart` as console.